# Draw heatmap for a given path using Google Maps api

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

How to draw heatmap for a given path using Google Maps Api.

```
function getPoints() {
  let heatMapArray = [];

  savedPaths.forEach((item) => {
  //here
  });
  return heatMapArray;
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your saved path should be an array of LatLng objects. You can use this data to add HeatmapLayer using google.maps.visualization.HeatmapLayer({data: savedPath}). Follow this documentation https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/heatmaplayer